# Не меняются параметры из php.ini

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

суть проблемы в том, что пытаюсь изменить файл php.ini. через phpinfo() подргуражется:

> "Loaded Configuration File    /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini"

Редактирую этот файл.
В данном случае мне нужен параметр `upload_max_filesize` (но ни какой параметр не изменяется), ставлю например 32M.
Сохраняю.
перезагружаю сервер `service nginx restart`.
При обновлении страницы все равно пишет

> upload_max_filesize 2M 2M

. при чем что php.info загружено

> Loaded Configuration File /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini

Comment: А зачем вы `nginx` перезагружаете? Если надо `php` рестарнуть?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.